# ReactJs - Loading cross domain assets

Tags: javascript, svg, cross-domain, reactjs

I created a React component to load svg from a url. It's pretty straightforward and uses the svg use syntax as a sprite sheet. Below is my code, I'm using ES6 syntax as well:

```
export class Icon extends React.Component {

  render() {
    var classes = "icon",
    url = this.props.url,
    definedClass = this.props.classes;

    if (definedClass) {
      classes = classes + ' ' + definedClass
    }

    return (
      <svg
        className={classes}
        viewBox="0 0 35 35"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:
          "<use xlink:href='" + url + "'></use></svg>"}}>
      </svg>
    )
  }
}
```

This works fine when loading from the same domain, but when I try to load this along with other code as a widget on a different domain I run into this error.

Unsafe attempt to load URL http://localhost:3123/assets/svg/star.svg from frame with URL http://localhost:8000/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Is there any way to get around this, or is this just default, unchangeable behavior in React?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue with React, but with how the browser handles cross-site references.

Comment: It's not React at all. It's the browser. In fact: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=470601 ... the last comment suggests that specific request is blocked in all browsers. You'd need to proxy the request through your web server (fetch it via the web server as it won't be restricted by a cross origin policy).

Answer (score 0):

as a side note, you cannot mix HTTP content with HTTPS (though it doesn't apply to your question)

add the lines below to .htaccess to allow CORS.

```
# with AJAX withCredentials=false (cookies NOT sent)
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]]

# with AJAX withCredentials=true (cookies sent, SSL allowed...)
SetEnvIfNoCase ORIGIN (.*) ORIGIN=$1
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN}e"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]
```